# Showing percent of upload of api angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-http

So I'm sending some data with a $http.post in angular like

```
 $http.post('/api/FileBrowser/UploadedFiles/',
                              JSON.stringify(dummyobj),
                              {
                                  headers: {
                                      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                                  }
                              }
                          ).success(function (data2) {

                          }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {

                          });
```

So now i want to try and show how many percent of the upload is done,
I know the size of the upload post call. so i would like to find something like a callback method that return how many send bytes,.

This should be doable since a browser can show this. any one how this can be done? Thanks

Comment: @danday74 answer is good. Otherwise when using $http which returns promise you can use a .then function in which you can define 3 callback : success/error/ and the last where you may be able to do that.

Comment: Indeed @danday74 got a good answer, but i was looking for a way to do it with my code base like shown. What you are talking about sounds like what i'm looking for. I been looking around for the last callback of the http promise. but can't find any informations about this. would you describe it a little more?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q Chapter "The Promise API" : then(successCallback, errorCallback, notifyCallback). I don't know if $http is using it to let you know about the progress

Comment: funny, could find that at all. im gonna look into it, an report back. thanks walfrat

Comment: So i tried it out, an could not get it to work. and is once again at a lost. don't know if its curse im trying to do it in a directive. even though i can't think of a reason, that would make it crash

Comment: I just checked ng-file-upload, it seems they ddo use http but perform a fix on it. Check the service UploadBase, function sendHttp. In my javascript file it's from line 450 to 490.

Comment: True, since i couldn't get it to work any other way, i been looking at the ng-file-upload, but can't get the post call to work like it do now, where i send the object as the body in the request. guess i'm too inspired to use this library

Answer (score 2):

use ng-file-upload

i've used it before for large company in production - works great - excellent when used in conjuntion with ui.bootstrap progress bars

https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/progressbar

both are well respect libraries within the Angular community

code from ng-file-upload site

```
//inject directives and services.
var app = angular.module('fileUpload', ['ngFileUpload']);

app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'Upload', function ($scope, Upload) {
// upload later on form submit or something similar
$scope.submit = function() {
  if ($scope.form.file.$valid && $scope.file) {
    $scope.upload($scope.file);
  }
};

// upload on file select or drop
$scope.upload = function (file) {
    Upload.upload({
        url: 'upload/url',
        data: {file: file, 'username': $scope.username}
    }).then(function (resp) {
        console.log('Success ' + resp.config.data.file.name + 'uploaded. Response: ' + resp.data);
    }, function (resp) {
        console.log('Error status: ' + resp.status);
    }, function (evt) {
        var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
        console.log('progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' + evt.config.data.file.name);
    });
};
// for multiple files:
$scope.uploadFiles = function (files) {
  if (files && files.length) {
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      Upload.upload({..., data: {file: files[i]}, ...})...;
    }
    // or send them all together for HTML5 browsers:
    Upload.upload({..., data: {file: files}, ...})...;
  }
}
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. i will indeed remember this for some other time, but i can't change the why i use the http upload for this assignment. so i'm afraid i need a way to do it like walfrat comment